# How can I assign dynamic ips to machines on my local network?

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, home-networking

I have comcast as my ISP. Now... I have a question, and I want to know if this is even possible to do. I noticed when I'm on my phone (Verizon), flick off LTE and then flick it on, my IP address changes upon flicking it on and off everytime. Is it possible to make this true with machines on my local network? So, say I connect my laptop to WiFi, then disconnect it, I want to get a NEW ip address every time this action is done.

Comment: I have changed the scope of my question.

Comment: You're looking not for dynamic IPs, but a very short lease and very aggressive scavenging of available IPs. The default DHCP server in the Comcast setup may not have these options available, and even if they do, they won't just assign a new IP by disconnecting and reconnecting. If you could add WHY you want this setup or what problem you're actually trying to solve with this quick-switch IP setup, that may help us find you a better solution you haven't yet considered.

Comment: @music2myear I am running a web scraping script that collects data. I need new _residential_ IP's in order to collect the data.

Comment: You will want to contact Comcast to see if this is something they can support.  There isn't anything on your end that can accomplish your end goal (except to call Comcast)

Comment: Probably not possible to do this. I doubt Comcast is going to edit their DHCP server settings just for you. You need to wait out the DHCP lease / scavenging settings on their DHCP server. The lease time is probably around 24 hours; you would have to dig into your router settings to confirm. You also need to be careful about your router renewing your lease every half-lease-time (or whatever it is configured to do). This resets the clock back to a full lease-time remaining.

Comment: @andy I don't think this has anything to do with the Comcast DHCP server. DHCP on OPs network is handled by the modem provided by Comcast, which likely lacks the required settings, but this doesn't ask upstream for any feedback or instructions regarding IP address assignment.

Comment: @music2myear OP changed the question from LAN IP Address to Public IP Address. And now it looks like he changed it back again. So...its an old comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I noticed when I'm on my phone (Verizon), if I flick off LTE and then flick it on again, my IP address changes upon flicking it on and off everytime. Is it possible to make this true with machines on my local network?

It may be theoretically possible to set up a system which allowed you to do something similar locally but it would only affect the IPs of the machines on your network (not your IP from Comcast).

> I am running a web scraping script that collects data. I need new *residential* IP's in order to collect the data.

If you Google something like "Rotating Proxy", you may find a service that will (supposedly) allow you to use multiple residential IPs. But there is no way (at least that I am aware of) to force Comcast to give you a new IP.